# How to prevent Graphviz from moving nodes to accomodate an edge

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to reproduce the following figure using Graphviz:

[image]

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
digraph
{
  rankdir="LR";
  splines=polyline;

  b [shape=circle, label="", style=filled, color=gray, width=0.2, height=0.2];
  c [shape=box, label="C(s)", style=filled, color=gray, xlabel=controller];
  d [shape=box, label="P(s)", style=filled, color=gray, xlabel=plant];
  a [shape=point, color=transparent, label="a"];
  e [shape=point, color=transparent, label="e"];
  f [shape=point, color=transparent, label="f"];

  c -> d [label="u"]
  b -> c [label="e"]
  a -> b [label="r"]
  d -> e [dir=none]
  e -> f [label="y"]
  e -> b
}
```

This gets me close but not quite there yet, as `dot` seems to move the nodes to accomodate the edge from `e` to `b` and not the other way round:

[image]

How do I get it so that the edge from `e` to `b` bends *around* the nodes rather than displacing them?

Answer (score 0):

(lots of trial-and-error)

- used html records to contrail external label positioning
- **constraint=false** & **dir=back** for **e->b** edge
- turned off edge clipping as needed to improve edges

```
digraph {
  // lines were rearranged just to simplify my comprehension
  rankdir="LR";
  splines=polyline;
  //splines=ortho;  // might work, if edges use xlabels
 
  a [shape=point, color=transparent, label="a"];
  b [shape=circle, label="", style=filled, fillcolor=gray, width=0.2, height=0.2];

  // c & d use html tables to better position exterior labels
  c [shape=plaintext label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" >
    <TR>   <TD>controller</TD>   </TR>
    <TR>   <TD border="1" port="p0" bgcolor="grey">C(s)</TD>   </TR>
    </TABLE>>];

  d [shape=plaintext label=<<TABLE BORDER="0">
    <TR>   <TD>plant</TD>   </TR>
    <TR>   <TD border="1" port="p0" bgcolor="grey">C(s)</TD>   </TR>
    </TABLE>>];
  
  e [shape=point width=.01 label=""];
  f [shape=point width=.00  label="" color=white];

  a -> b [label="r"]
  b -> c:p0 [label="e"]
  c:p0:e -> d:p0:w [label="u"]
  d:p0 -> e [dir=none headclip=false]
  e -> f [label="y" tailclip=false headclip=false]

  b -> e [dir=back constraint=false]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Seriously? I wasn't expecting it to be this complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above, wouldn't  changing:

```
  e -> b
```

into

```
  e -> b [dir=none constraint=false]
```

i.e.

```
digraph
{
  rankdir="LR";
  splines=polyline;

  b [shape=circle, label="", style=filled, color=gray, width=0.2, height=0.2];
  c [shape=box, label="C(s)", style=filled, color=gray, xlabel=controller];
  d [shape=box, label="P(s)", style=filled, color=gray, xlabel=plant];
  a [shape=point, color=transparent, label="a"];
  e [shape=point, color=transparent, label="e"];
  f [shape=point, color=transparent, label="f"];

  c -> d [label="u"]
  b -> c [label="e"]
  a -> b [label="r"]
  d -> e [dir=none]
  e -> f [label="y"]
  e -> b [dir=none constraint=false]
}
```

as on: http://www.webgraphviz.com/

I get:

[image]

(Disadvantage we still have a small gap at the line labeled `y`).

Comment: That seems more straightforward than what  @sroush suggested. I don't mind the gap, but would it be possible to increase the vertical space between the square nodes and the edge from `e` to `b?

Comment: I think this is possible by defining lengths and maybe some extra nodes on the `e -> b` edge and even connecting these extra nodes through invisible edges with the boxes (but at that moment everything gets quit complicated again)